# Is this famous identity for indefinite integrals axiom or theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Let say that $A(x)$ describes area under $f(x)$ in the interval $[0, x]$ ($x$ varies). Then, if we sum up all infinitesimally small rectangles each of area $f(x)dx$ for all $x$-values in the domain of $f(x)$ we will get exact area under $f(x)$ from $0$ to $x$.We write this process as $ \int_{0}^{x}f(x)dx = A(x).$

But, we can also easly prove that instant velocity of $A(x)$  for input $x$ is of course $f(x)$ (that is instant change in the added area, $f(x)dx,$ over $dx$ which is indeed $f(x)$). So, $\frac{d}{dx}A(x) = f(x).$

This was for some interval, but if we want $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ for whole number line, my intuition tells me that integral would be some function, not a number (except if x-axis is asymptote to both directions of our function, for example $e^{-x^2}$).
Now, my question.
How can we prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = A(x) + C?$$
I understand that $\frac{d}{dx} [A(x) + C] = \frac{d}{dx}A(x)$ but I can't see how can previous proven facts in calculus prove this. So, is this the definition, axiom or theorem which can be proven? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but what is the famous identity here?

Comment: When I said identity I meant on $$\int{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = A(x) + C$$ where $A(x)$ describes area

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \, dx$ means $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1\, dx$, alternaively written as $\int_{\Bbb{R}}1$, which is equal to $\infty$. i.e this is an improper Riemann-integral, which is equal to a "number", not a function. (I only put "number" in quotes because $\infty$ doesn't belong to $\Bbb{R}$, but this shouldn't distract you from the fact that the result of this integral is NOT a function)

Comment: How can the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ be a function of $x$? Isn't it an area or a limit of areas thus a number?

Comment: @peek-a-boo, edited

Comment: @Miguel, for example $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2dx = \frac{x^3}{3}$ so of course this is not a number, but a function

Comment: $\int f(x)dx$ is a function, namely $A(x)+C$. As soon as you put bounds, $\int a^b f(x)dx$, you are (roughly speaking) evaluating $(A(b)-A(a))$. What you end up with is a constant, and not a function.

Comment: @Graviton, yes I said that. I am asking if your first claim is an axiom, definition or theorem (which then can be proven)

Comment: Well, it is definitely not an axiom. Most axioms are so deeply rooted in logic that they evade even the concept of numbers. It would be silly to have things as high-level as calculus as an axiom. I believe what you're seeking is the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), which is a *theorem*. To be honest, it is very close to being more of a definition of integration than a theorem. Nonetheless, it is still regarded as a theorem, and as such, is something that can be *proved*, per se.

Comment: @1b3b I guess that you mean $\int x^2 dx$ rather than $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 dx$, but even then the primitive is **not** a function but a family of functions that differ in a constant.

Comment: You are abusing notation with variables. For example, you should write $A(x) = \int_0^ x f(t) dt$. The same thing happens later in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx$. $x$ is not a free variable in this integral so it is not sensible to write it as a function of $x$. Also, do you  mean to have $f$ as the integrand?

Comment: @Miguel, where is the difference?

Comment: @Graviton, thanks. I obviously seen FTC but I can't find there if $\int f(x)dx = A(x) + C$ is a definition or can be proven

Comment: @1b3b I would say everything. Primitive and definite integral are completely different concepts and they have different definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments on the question, it appears you are asking for an explanation of why $\int f(x) dx= A(x)+C$. This isn't the same was what appears in the question itself, but I can't make sense of the equation $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx= A(x)+C$. So my answer addresses the interpretation of your question based on the comments.

Define $A(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t) dt$. Then (part of) the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that $\frac{d}{dx} A(x) = f(x)$. Now, the notatation $\int f(x) dx$ denotes the *family* of antiderivatives of $f(x)$. We've just seen from FTC that $A(x)$ is *an* antiderivative of $f(x)$. If $F(x)$ is another antiderivative, then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(A(x)-F(x))= f(x)-f(x)=0
$$
It follows from this that $A(x)-F(x)$ is a constant function (by the Mean Value Theorem for example). So $F(x)=A(x)+C$ for some constant $C$.

*Conclusion:* $\int f(x) dx$  is precisely $A(x)+C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

*Edit:* To be more precise about answering your question, I wouldn't call this statement an axiom. Rather it is a corollary of two theorems: FTC and the fact that if a function's derivative is identically 0 then the function is constant.

*Edit 2:* It should also be emphasized that the notation $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is very different from $\int f(x) dx$. While the latter represents the family of all antiderivatives of $f(x)$, the former represents the net area under the graph of $f(x)$ over $(-\infty,\infty)$ which is a real number if it exists at all. You can connect this to $A(x)$ if you want to, e.g.,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) dx = \lim_{x\to\infty} A(x)+\lim_{x\to -\infty} A(x)
$$
But you have to be carefuly about the limits existing, and watch for $\infty-\infty$ situations, etc. But this would work for a nice function like $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: I thought $\int f(x)dx$ was just an abbreviation for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx.$ Thanks

Comment: Another question. $A(x)$ is antiderivative of $f(x)$ but only on $[0, x]$; not for whole domain of $f(x)$. So, we need area function, $A(x)$, from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: This doesn't parse because when you talk about $f(x)$ as a function on $[0,x]$ you are treating $x$ as both the independent variable of the function and as a fixed endpoint of the domain of the function. This kind of mixup is related to my comment on the original question, and why I (re-)defined $A(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$ in my answer. Similarly, "an area function $A(x)$ from $-\infty,\infty$" suggests that you want a function depending on a variable $x$, but there is no clear dependence on $x$. Either the area over $(-\infty,\infty)$ exists and is a fixed real number, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Anyway, we have $f(x)$ which is an integrable function in the variable $x$, with domain $(-\infty,\infty)$. For *any* $x$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$ we define $A(x)$ as the area under $f$ over $[0,x]$. So $A(x)$ is a well-defined function with domain $(-\infty,\infty)$. Now FTC implies that $A'(x)=f(x)$ for any $x$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Okay, we can write $\int f(x)dx$ as $\int_{a}^{b}$ for any $a < b, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and that's why is called indefinite integral. On the other hand, If we have area function for $f$ on, for example, $[0, t]$ (now $t$ varies), we know that $\frac{d}{dx}A(x) = f(x).$ So, one and only one antiderivative desribes area from $0$ to $t$ (again, $t$ varies). But, when we don't know area function we **know** that it must be one of antiderivatives. In that sense, for any $a, b$ we know that our wanted area function is one of these: $A(x) + C.$

Comment: It is important to mention that formula (again, for any real numbers $a, b$) $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)$ still works becuse we would have $A(b) + C - (A(a) + C) = A(b) - A(a).$  Take for example $\int_{a}^{b}2xdx,$ both $a, b$ varies. Then difference of values of quadratic function for $x = a$ and $x = b$ ($F(x) := x^2$... $F(b) - F(a)$) will nicely desribe area, but will also $F(x) + 3, F(x) - 10,$ etc. Is this finally it? :)